# Application Deployment -- No Audio, No Images on client side

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, deployment, windows-7

I am deploying an application written in Qt + OpenGL, written in Visual Studio 2008 for windows 7.

On client machine, no audio is played and no images are displayed in application. I am keeping it very simple. No different folders for images and audio files, everything is sitting near .exe  In my code I have accessed these files like

```
QPixmap pixmap("closeButton.jpg");
```

Now the funny thing is it works "Perfectly" on my computer. So I am not getting where the problem is

I tried Output directory from /Release to /myProject where all the source files and image and audio files are present. Again, it works on my computer, but not on client side.

As I can not generate similar problem on my machine, its getting really hard to solve the issue. Is there a good solution ?

Comment: I am yet to try .qrc files. It seems to be the last thing I can try; but what is the issue with this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Problem is solved now. I was actually missing two dlls, each for audio and images from

Qt\Version\Plugins\ directory. Dependency walker does not show plugin dependencies.

Also referring to the comments to the 1st answer, Qt Resources are actually packed inside binary. [image: See here]

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

You seriously need to add audio/images and any other external files as **resources** to the project.

For instance, I wrote a code that loads an image into a `QImage` widget. The properties of my resources file is:

[image]

Later on the code I refer to the file as:

```
QImage tmp(":/mario-block.png");
```

Another important part of the deal is to verify if the resource has been loaded properly, so in this case I also added the lines:

```
if (tmp.isNull())
{
    std::cout << "!!! Failed to load image #1" << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: may be my basic concepts are not clear as this is my first deployment; but I am not really convinced why should I add them to project? they are in same directory and path is also good..

Comment: Updated. Check the 2nd part of the answer, it states the importance of coding safely and always checking the success of the stuff you do. If your code fails to open a file, it's usually due to 1 of 2  reasons: 1) the PATH to the file is wrong; 2) you don't have the right filesystem permissions to do so.

Comment: ok.. now adding .qrc file, will check with client tomorrow due to timezone differences.. thanks for explanation :)

Comment: Ok. Notice that the prefix I chose for my project implicates that the image will be located in the same directory as the binary application. ;)

Comment: a quick question --> what should I include in my deployment package? .qtc file? i thought I would get binaries of all images etc.. but I can't find them. Or are they inside .exe? And should I include image and files again in the package? it won;t make sense if I have to include naked files again..

Comment: They are not packed inside the binary. [Qt Resources](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/resources.html) just make it easier for you to refer to those files inside your source code. You still have to ship the external files along with your application, unless you do some magic and configure the resource to be stored inside your application. But this doesn't happen by default.

Comment: well.. the issue remains. I added resource files also.. but client is still not able to see images and hear the audio. I have some .tga files.. which are successfully used in the project.. Anything else you think is worth trying?

Comment: Can you see the debug messages that are displayed in case the loading fails?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your images and audio files are included in setup package? And if you access the files, do you use the correct path to them?

Comment: yes. those are present near exe on client machine also. they are in good condition also means audio files can be played independently. the same package i installed on my computer, then it works!

Comment: Shouldn't this answer be a comment instead?